# iOS: Is it possible to resize Twitter and/or Facebook login button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, twitter

I want to add Twitter and Facebook authentication buttons to my mobile app. Currently using XCode 6 and the newest SDKs of Facebook and Twitter. I managed to integrate these two buttons into my auth screen, but the sizes are really different, resulting in a really horrible design issue ; )

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // facebook login
    FBSDKLoginButton *fbLogin = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    fbLogin.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:fbLogin];

    // twitter login
    TWTRLogInButton *twLogin = [TWTRLogInButton buttonWithLogInCompletion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
        // ...
    }];
    twLogin.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y+50.0);
    [self.view addSubview:twLogin];
}
```

**Somebody any idea how to resize those buttons ?**

EDIT-1: Based on Sega-Zero's answer I get the following error:

```
2015-05-31 11:20:12.204 TestApp[10477:3081595] [Fabric] Unable to locate application icon
2015-05-31 11:20:12.251 TestApp[10477:3081595] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Expected a view 
H:fbLogin(==twLogin) 
  ^'
```

EDIT-2: Based on Sega-Zero's corrected answer I get the following error:

```
2015-05-31 11:39:11.433 Quiz Cup[10486:3083839] [Fabric] Unable to locate application icon
2015-05-31 11:39:11.488 Quiz Cup[10486:3083839] The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x170088840 FBSDKLoginButton:0x124e12690'Log in'.width == TWTRLogInButton:0x124e15840.width>
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
2015-05-31 11:39:11.490 Quiz Cup[10486:3083839] View hierarchy unprepared for constraint.
    Constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x170088840 FBSDKLoginButton:0x124e12690'Log in'.width == TWTRLogInButton:0x124e15840.width>
    Container hierarchy: 
<FBSDKLoginButton: 0x124e12690; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (296.5 497; 175 30); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x170036d80>>
   | <UIButtonLabel: 0x124e147a0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); text = 'Log in'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x170087f80>>
    View not found in container hierarchy: <TWTRLogInButton: 0x124e15840; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (244 542; 280 40); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1740322e0>>
    That view's superview: <UIView: 0x124e11960; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x170036c00>>
2015-05-31 11:39:11.497 Quiz Cup[10486:3083839] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint:<NSLayoutConstraint:0x170088840 FBSDKLoginButton:0x124e12690'Log in'.width == TWTRLogInButton:0x124e15840.width> view:<FBSDKLoginButton: 0x124e12690; baseClass = UIButton; frame = (296.5 497; 175 30); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x170036d80>>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a minumum width/height constraints + equal width/height for both buttons.
If you prefer to do that via code, this may look like this:

```
[fbLoginParent addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[fbLogin(==twLogin)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(fbLogin, twLogin)]];
[fbLoginParent addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[fbLogin(==twLogin)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(fbLogin, twLogin)]];
[fbLogin addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[fbLogin(>=100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(fbLogin)]];
[fbLogin addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[fbLogin(>=26)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(fbLogin)]];
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I get some kind of syntax error with your solution... Please see at "EDIT-1" in the original question. Any ideas?

Comment: By the way, is it somehow possible to place the FB and TWTR buttons visually in XCode 6 like other views ?

Comment: Sorry, corrected constraint format, i wrote it without book =)

Comment: And yes, you are able to place it via Interface Builder. Just place UIView control and set it's custom class to FBSDKLoginButton/TWTRLogInButton

Comment: Now I get a even more complex error ;-) Btw. you used "fbLoginParent" in your corrected answer (line 1+2). This object doesn't exist in the code, did you mean "fbLogin" ? The new error is at EDIT-2 in the original question. Okay, but otherwise I will try to place the two buttons visually...

Comment: This means you should add a constraints to fbLogin's parent =)

Comment: The programmatic gives me some constraint violations back. But the visual approach you suggested works fine and is appropriate for my current needs. Therefore I will accept your answer. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**For Facebook Login Button : All what you need is a button in your view "which can be customize now :D" and IBAction linked to this button**

```
-(IBAction)do_FaceBook_Login:(id)sender {

    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];


                        [login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile",@"user_birthday",@"email"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                            if (error) {
                                // Process error

                                NSLog(@"error get permission");

                            } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                                // Handle cancellations

                                NSLog(@"cancel get permission");

                            } else {
                                // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
                                // should check if specific permissions missing

                                if ([result.grantedPermissions
                                     containsObject:@"user_birthday"] && [result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
                                    // Do work

                                    [self handleStatusDependOnSession];

                    }
                }
            }];
```

}

**This will not allow to the user to login until he give u all the permissions u asked for it after that u can fetch user info :**

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                                            [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
                                             startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                                                 if (!error) {
                                                     NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
                                                 }
                                             }];
}
```

**For more detail u can visit Facebook Developer site and read the document where u can found that there is two way to login :**

1- Using [Facebook Login for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3#login-button)

or

2 - Using [FBSDKLoginManager](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.3#login-apicalls) "which allow u to customize your button"

Comment: Hi Omarj - many thanks for your help. I will study your links in more depth soon as I progress with the FB SDK :-) For now, I just wanted to resize the buttons :-) I give you a big vote up - thank you very much!

Comment: your welcome any time :D I had the same problem as you , with more complexity , that when I found that u can create your own custom button and do what ever you want.

Comment: I already realized that I have to dig deeper into the FB SDK :-D ! Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

I manually resized the Facebook button to match the Twitter one.

```
CGRect newFrame = _loginButton.frame;
newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(220, 50);
_loginButton.frame = newFrame;
_loginButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
```